# SharePoint 2013: Creating an alert for a list size limit

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to know if its possible to create an alert for when a list reaches a specified size? I understand that managing the view settings is the "ideal" way to deal with this issue but my case is a little different.

We have views setup as a make-shift dashboard for a client, so having the limit actually works for us as far as being a build-in way to manage library size. For us having an alert for when the list view is approaching the limit saves us a huge headache because when it reaches the 5k limit it breaks the workflows attached to list. I'd prefer to have a workflow that simply moves old items into another folder, buuuut we need to actually choose which files to "archive".

Any help or guidance would be GREATLY appreciated!

thanks,

Terek

Comment: Refer this answer. This should work for you -- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6855d996-21a8-4d68-af9c-2e2b49db6862/how-do-you-create-an-alert-for-a-list-size-limit?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: did you mean to send the link to my post?

Comment: I didn't know this question is posted by you only :). Anyway I meant the answer that suggests to use `designer workflow`.